# fgets vs. std::fgets - lines are missed by fgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, fgets

I have the following code: (cpp14)

```
static int const max_len = 1000;
FILE* m_in_log = NULL;
FILE* m_log = NULL;
...

...


bool readLine(char* line, int max_len) 
    if(!fgets(line, max_len, m_in_log)) {
        return false;
    }

    fputs(line, m_log);
    fflush(m_log);
    return true;
}
```

It is supposed to read line by line from a log file and then write it, as is, into a different log file.

It is a part of a complex multithreaded system which runs in linux and the `m_in_log` input is a FIFO.

When I run this code multiple times, something it misses lines:

suppose `m_in_log` contains the following lines:

> AAA
>
> BBB
>
> CCC
>
> DDD
>
> EEE

but the the output log file I only see

> AAA
>
> EEE

meaning fgets missed reading the 3 lines in the middle (I know for a fact that these line were send to the FIFO because we also do `tee` from this FIFO to another file, and in this file all the 5 lines are written).

After struggling with this issue for some time (without any luck) I decided to use `std` methods:

```
fgets => std::fgets

fputs => std::fputs

fflush => std::fflush
```

and it seems like the problems is solved.

Could you please explain why using `std` methods may solve this issue?

Comment: How do you know it's not the `tee` process that's dropping the lines?

Comment: I thought about it, but I use tee also with the std::fgets

Comment: you mention multithreading, is there concurrent access to log reads/writes? if not, check what happens if you read individual characters with fgetc/fputc. there may also be a line ending issue, with mixed DOS/UNIX style line endings

Comment: @SvenNilsson this part of the system is not multithreaded - there is only one owner to this class and all the read / write is not concurrent.
Regarding individual characters  - I added printf for the chars in line after the fgets and I do not see the missing lines

Comment: @AlexL: The `std` functions you refer to are just the C functions wrapped in the `std` namespace, nothing more. They are functionally the same as the originals. If you really wanted to re-write the C code in C++, you should be using `std::ifstream` with `std:getline()` for input, and `std::ofstream` for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Remy Lebeau suggested, there is not really a difference between `fgets` and `std::fgets`, and after running the code with `std::fgets` for ~20 hours the issue was reproduced.

So I guess I need to search for the problem in some other place.

Thank you all!